# Select from a table only the columns that are not empty?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with hundreds of columns:

```
------------------------------------------------
ID    ColA    ColB    ColC  Col D   ...   ColZZZ
------------------------------------------------
1             bla
2     foo
3     bar
4                                         baz
------------------------------------------------
```

I need to know which columns have no values in them (that is: which are empty `''` not `NULL`)

I could create a query for every column:

```
select count(1) from [table] where [ColA] <> ''; -- returns 2, so not, not empty
select count(1) from [table] where [ColB] <> ''; -- returns 1, so no
select count(1) from [table] where [ColC] <> ''; -- returns 0, so yay! found and empty one
...
etc
```

But there has to be an easier way for this?

Is there a way to return `[table]` without the empty columns, in other words:

```
----------------------------
ID    ColA    ColB    ColZZZ
----------------------------
1             bla
2     foo
3     bar
4                     baz
----------------------------
```

Comment: No.  A SQL query has a fixed set of columns.  You cannot choose entire columns conditionally.

Comment: So I have to go by them 1 by 1, noting the ones that are empty, and then build my next queries without adding those columns to my select or where clauses? I'm willing to do it, but shouldn't there be a way to dynamically do this?

Comment: It can be done dynamically using a cursor on system view sys.colums... I have done something similar looking for empty columns, I'll try to find it and rewrite it as example...

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution to it. I used this query before too search for empty columns across all tables. Slightly modified now to search for non-empty, it might have few extra parts not needed in you example.

You create a temp table to store column names that are not empty, and use cursor to create dynamic sql to search for them.

In the end, just generate another dynamic sql to select columns based on temp table results.

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpRez') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE #tmpRez;
CREATE TABLE #tmpRez (TableName sysname, ColName sysname);

DECLARE crs CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT t.name, c.name FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN  sys.columns c ON c.object_id=t.object_id
    WHERE 1=1
    AND t.name = 'Table1' -- OR your own condition

OPEN crs;

DECLARE @tbl sysname;
DECLARE @col sysname;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

FETCH NEXT FROM crs INTO @tbl,@col;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @sql = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ['+ @tbl+'] WHERE [' + @col + '] <> '''') INSERT INTO #tmpRez SELECT ''' + @tbl +''','''+ @col + '''';
    EXEC(@sql);
    FETCH NEXT FROM crs INTO @tbl,@col;
END;

CLOSE crs;
DEALLOCATE crs;   

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ' + STUFF((SELECT ',' + ColName FROM #tmpRez x
            where x.TableName = y.TableName
    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')  + ' FROM ' + TableName 
FROM #tmpRez y GROUP BY TableName   

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Many thanks for this! But am I correct that this would only work if the columns would have `null` values (which they never do, instead there will be an empty string (`''`) instead).

Comment: @Pr0no - yep you are right - here it's modified now to look for empty string

Answer (score 0):

How about this to return the table with no empty columns:

```
SELECT * from table 
WHERE column IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(column) <> ''
```

This to return the table with empty columns:

```
SELECT * from table 
WHERE column IS NULL AND TRIM(column) = ''
```